# ¿Podemos usar los pronombres directos/indirectos en una respuesta para referirnos a un objeto abstracto (sin el artículo) mencionado antes?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

¿Podemos usar los pronombres directos/indirectos en una respuesta para referirnos a un objeto abstracto (sin el artículo) mencionado antes (por ejemplo, mencionado en una pregunta o en una oración anterior)?

**Hay una regla**: "El artículo se suele omitir antes de un objeto directo, cuando se trata de la clase de objeto, no de un objeto concreto. Si esto ocurre en una pregunta, en la respuesta no se hace ninguna referencia a la clase de objeto: ¿*Tienes bici*? → *No, no tengo*. (Y no: *No, no la tengo.*)."

Basándonos en esa regla, ¿tenemos que omitir el pronombre directo en estos casos abajo y decir lo mismo de alguna otra manera? Aunque en esa regla no se trata de un objeto abstracto, sino de la clase de objeto.

Pregunta: *"¿Podríamos bajar algo más el precio valorando la opción de utilizar **colágeno**?"*

Respuesta: "*No, no **lo** podéis utilizar.*

Y aquí también - ¿tenemos que omitir el pronombre indirecto y decir lo mismo de alguna otra forma?

"*Siempre empezamos con **términos de prepago** (pago adelantado). Pero después de que tengamos una buena historia de colaboración podemos revisar**los**.*"

Y también aquí, esta vez con el pronombre indirecto - ¿tenemos que omitirlo y decir lo mismo de algún otro modo?

"*Estamos trabajando con **personas con influencia** que puedan ser como **embajadores** de la marca y puedan ser de todos los ámbitos posibles (e-sports, el esqui, el natación, el boxeo y otros  los entusiastas del ejercicio físico). **Les** aportamos con un descuento por nuestros productos y además **les** proporcionamos con los productos gratuitamente para que los promoveranpromuevan.*"

Y, como una información adicional, soy consciente de que NO podemos decir así":

"***Un** instrumento **lo** puedes aplicar así.*"

Pero SÍ que podemos decir así:

"***El** instrumento **lo** puedes aplicar así.*"

"***Este** instrumento **lo** puedes aplicar así.*"

Y cuando nos hacen esa pregunta abajo, podemos responder así (**creo** que podemos):

"*Tienes **un** coche?*"

"*No, no **lo** tengo*"

Aunque no están relacionados con la pregunta mía (porque en mi pregunta se trata de los sustantivos **sin ningún determinante**), se me ocurrieron esos ejemplos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcta la regla mencionada en el sentido de que, cuando se usa un sustantivo indeterminado en posición de objeto, no se usa pronombre átono para hacer referencia al sustantivo. Esto ocurre con sustantivos en singular con artículo indefinido o sin artículo y con sustantivos en plural sin artículo definido u otro determinante que los defina (ej. demostrativos, posesivos). En todos los demás casos, se usa pronombre:

- ¿Tienes (un) auto? / No, no tengo.
- ¿Tienes **el** auto? / No, no **lo** tengo.
- ¿Tienes autos? / No, no tengo.
- ¿Tienes dos autos? / No, no tengo.
- ¿Tienes **los** dos autos? / No, no **los** tengo.
- ¿Trajiste **tu** auto? / No, no **lo** traje.
- ¿Trajiste **tus** autos? / No, no **los** traje.
- ¿Viste **ese** auto? / No, no **lo** vi.
- ¿Viste **esos** autos? / No, no **los** vi.
- ¿Tienes coraje para conducir? / No, no tengo.
- ¿Tienes **el** coraje para conducir? / No, no **lo** tengo.

En respuesta a la pregunta adicional de OP en los comentarios, la regla precedente aplica a preguntas y respuestas. En otros tipos de oraciones, puede usarse pronombre átono para referirse a **un sustantivo indeterminado que, en el curso del texto, se vuelve determinado**:

- Tengo un auto azul en el garaje y **lo** voy a manejar hoy (voy a manejar **el** auto azul que tengo en el garaje).
- Tengo (varios)  autos y **los** voy a manejar hoy (voy a manejar **los** autos que tengo).
- No tengo coraje para manejar pero **lo** voy a conseguir (voy a conseguir el coraje necesario para manejar).

A veces, el sustantivo sigue siendo indeterminado:

- No tengo nafta así que voy a cargar. (NO: **la** voy a cargar)

Comment: Lo que escribiste se aplica solamente en caso de respuestas a preguntas? O lo aplica en general? Por ejemplo, puedo decir así "Tengo un coche azul y lo voy a conducir luego"? O una persona menciona "Tengo un coche azul en mi garaje" y le hago una pregunta así "Y lo vas a manejar hoy?".

Comment: Y también si puedo decir así "Tengo autos y los voy a manejar hoy"? Es posible decir así?

Comment: Agregué la respuesta a tu pregunta.